# PhantomJS webdriver error code -6

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am running a Python script on a remote server that scrapes periodically a webpage, using PhantomJS as a webdriver in Selenium.

The script stops unexpectedly after running for some hours, throwing the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "long.py", line 74, in <module>
    data = scrape_page_long()
  File "long.py", line 19, in scrape_page_long
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -6
```

I thought at first it had to do with ssl errors (hence the arguments), but it doesn't seem related I think.

Any ideas on what causes this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Your script is never able to scrape the web page, because PhantomJS is not working at all on the server.

If you log into the server and run `phantomjs --version` you'll see this:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
PhantomJS has crashed. Please read the bug reporting guide at
<http://phantomjs.org/bug-reporting.html> and file a bug report.
Aborted
```

You can fix this by adding `export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen` to your user account's `.bashrc`, or by adding `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen` to the server's `/etc/environment`.